How to run async function in parallel but with a timeout after the first one resolves? | Promise.all with timeout after first resolves
Let's say I have async functions calling external APIs with variable response times defined as below:
async function promise1() { /* API Call */ }
async function promise2() { /* API Call */ }
async function promise3() { /* API Call */ }
// ... up to promiseN

If I wanted to run them all in parallel and wait for all of them to resolve, I would run them like result = Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3,...,promiseN]).
However, I have a slightly different requirement:

I want to start all the promises in parallel.
As soon as the first one resolves (whichever that is), I want to wait 500 milliseconds for the other promises to resolve.
After that 500 ms window, I want to ignore any remaining unresolved promises.
result should contain all the promises that resolved by the time the 500 ms window ends. However, if all other promises other than the first resolve or reject before the 500 ms window ends, then we must return immediately rather than waiting until the end of it.

So for example, if promise2 resolves first at time T, I want to wait until T + 500 ms for the others to resolve. Any promises that haven't resolved by then should be ignored.
How can I accomplish this in JavaScript?
EDIT:
Thank you for all the answers! An important requirement that I forgot to add is that if the remaining promises resolve before the 500 ms window, then we should return immediately.

you can flag a variable isCancel when time is over. on the then of each promise do an if (isCancel) return; to ignore the resolution

"I would run them like result = Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3,...,promiseN]).": but that doesn't run your async functions. You defined promise1 as a function, not as a promise. This doesn't do what you described. Did you intend to add parentheses?

What should happen when any promise rejects, do you want to propagate the error, ignore it, or crash your application? What should happen when it rejects before the first fulfills, when it rejects during the 500ms of waiting, when it rejects afterwards?

Do you care about the order of the results, i.e. the indices in the result array being the same as the respective promise in the input? That's what Promise.all and Promise.allSettled do.

Just for the record, your question shows result = Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3,...,promiseN])., but that is not correct because you show those symbols to be functions, not promises.  You have to CALL your promiseN functions to start the operations and get their returned promise as in result = Promise.all([promise1(), promise2(), promise3(),...,promiseN()])..  Perhaps just a typo, but thought I'd point it out in case that's a misunderstanding.

You could await for the first promise to fulfill with Promise.any. Then create a timeout promise (that rejects after 5 seconds), and let each of the promises race with that timeout promise. Await the results with Promise.allSettled.
Here is a demo:


// Helper functions
const delay = (ms, value) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(value), ms));
const timeout = (ms, err) => new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(err), ms));

// Create a list of asynchronous functions for the demo
// They fulfull after 2, 4, 6, 8, or 10 seconds respectively, and provide as value that number of seconds.
const asyncTasks = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10].map(i => () => delay(1000 * i, "value " + i));

async function main() {
    // Create all the promises
    let promises = asyncTasks.map(task => task());
    console.log("Promises are created. Waiting for one of them to fulfill...");
    // Await a fulfilment 
    try { 
        await Promise.any(promises);
    } catch (e) {} // Silent also when all promises reject
    console.log("A promise fulfilled (or all rejected). Start timer...");
    const timer = timeout(5000, "timeout");
    // Let each of the promises race with the timer:
    promises = promises.map(p => Promise.race([p, timer]));
    // Await all these race-promises to settle
    const results = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
    console.log("Here are the results:");
    for (const result of results) console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}

main();




Thanks, this works! Would you happen to know how to modify your solution so that we don't wait until the end of the 5000 ms timeout if all promises have settled or rejected before then?

It already works like that. If in the snippet above, you replace the timeout with 50000 (so 10 times as long -- 50 seconds), it will not take 50 seconds to get the result, but 10 seconds, which is how long it takes for the last promise to settle.

Oh sweet! Marking this as the answer since it contains working code.

I wanted to point out that the call within the try catch needs to be Promise.any rather than Promise.race because we want to wait for at least 1 of them to resolve before starting the timer.
The other thing to mention is that the timer function I wrote is a little more involved such that it clears the timer if the promise resolves before the timeout.
Other than that, everything is correct!

Alright, you know best what you expect to happen, I guess ;-) Your question didn't really specify what should happen when one or more promises rejected, so I made some assumptions. Now I have updated it to wait for the first fulfillment of a promise. Note that if you clear the timer, the associated promise remains pending. I wouldn't worry about that timer: there is no problem in a timer that still resolves a promise after all (other) promises resolved, as this code wouldn't be listening to that event anymore.

Yes absolutely, I don't think there's any problem with your original solution but wanted to post this comment for anyone who may come across this same question. On second thought, maybe I will update the question with the solution I went with.

If you want to post the solution you went with, don't edit it into the question. Instead post it as an answer. That is how Stack Overflow works: questions & answers should be strictly separated.

Instead of Promise.all you will need Promise.any (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any) and chain a .then(), incapsulating your 500ms wait into a second promise, which, when fulfilled, so 500ms passed after the first promise fulfilled and proceed with your flow without waiting for the other promises to be fulfilled.

Thanks Lajos! @Yogi could I bug you to post the code please?

"loop your promises and reject those which were not fulfilled yet." - that's not how promises work, you cannot reject them from outside.

@Bergi thanks for your comment. Edited my answer.

This is my attempt to implement the logic that @lajos-arpad suggested.  As he described I use the first resolved promise of Promise.any to trigger a second promise the resolves after a 500ms timeout.   After the delay I pack all of the resolved promises into an array and resolve the 2nd promise.


function d(delay, error = false) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("logged :: ", delay)
      if (error) {
        rej(new Error(`error ${delay}`))
        return
      }
      res(`done ${delay}`)

    }, delay);
  });
}


async function go() {
  const promises = [d(1000), d(1200), d(1400, true), d(1500), d(1600), d(5000)]
  await Promise.any(promises);
  const res = []
  promises.forEach((p) => {
    p.then(r => res.push({
      status: "fulfilled",
      value: r
    })).catch(e => res.push({
      status: "rejected",
      reason: `${e}`
    }))
  })
  const delayedResults = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {

    resolve([...res])
  }, 500))
  console.log("delayed results :: ", delayedResults)

}

go();



I have edited my answer per comments and added error handling.  It now returns patterned on Promise.allSettled

You should put the promises.forEach(p => p.then(r => res.push(r))) before the delay, you need to handle rejections in there, and you should add a flag so that res is no longer mutated after the delay (and after the function returned it)

I'm not sure how a flag would work.  How about just spreading the results like so?  resolve([...res])

That would also do, yes. For the flag it's just let returned = false; for (const p of promises) p.then(r => if (!returned) res.push(r), err => …); await delay(500); returned = true; return res;

@Bergi I have made some changes per your comments.

in your Api function only try to add delay if your 500ms are not completed.
if completed don't save answer, if not completed call endawait() function
mark completed true in endawait() function
const ans = [null, null, null];
const extra_wait = 500;
let completed = false;

async function promise1() {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 900)); // api call
    if (completed) return;
    ans[0] = 1;
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, extra_wait));
    endWait();
}
async function promise2() {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500)); // api call
    if (completed) return;
    ans[1] = 2;
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, extra_wait));
    endWait();
}
async function promise3() {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1500)); // api call
    if (completed) return;
    ans[2] = 3;
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, extra_wait));
    endWait();
}


function endWait() {
    if (completed) return;
    completed = true;
    console.log(ans);
}

promise1();
promise2();
promise3();

